# Perl - create objects but how to get at the individual object?

Tags: perl, oop

I create objects but then don't know how to easily use them once they are created (do set/get and run methods). The code below works but then I cannot get at the object to use it How do I do this?

```
# My array of coffeecup names
my @coffeeCupNames = ("Espresso", "Sumatran", "Java");

# Create an array to hold my objects once they are created
my @objects = ();

# Create a new coffee cup object with the name of the coffee cup
foreach (@coffeeCupNames)
{
    push @objects, new virtualCoffeeObject("$_");
}

# How do I get at the Espresso coffee cup object?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with all hints the other answers give but I don't see why nobody posted the obvious solution to keep track of the created objects.

Of course you can store your objects in dedicated scalar variables:

```
my $espresso = VirtualCoffee->new("Espresso");
my $sumatran = VirtualCoffee->new("Sumatran");
...
```

As you draw your coffee types from an array you'll probably not want to use fixed variable names for all your coffees. The tool of choice for this is a hash in Perl.

```
my @coffee_cup_names = ("Espresso", "Sumatran", "Java");

# create a VirtualCoffee object and store it with its name as hash key
my %coffees = map {$_ => VirtualCoffee->new($_)} @coffee_cup_names;

# how to get the objects:
my @coffee_sorts = keys   %coffees;
my @all_coffees  = values %coffees;
my $espresso = $coffees{Espresso};
```

To learn more about hashes in Perl, I recommend the [Modern Perl "book" (read online)](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl/chapter_03.html#aGFzaGVz).

I allowed myself to adapt your variable names to common Perl style.

Comment: Daniel, thank you for the Hash magic!! Thank you so much!! I had been beating my head against the wall for 3 days on this. Now I can easily create and manipulate objects. Thanks again! - Jason

Comment: I'm glad my hint to hashes did the trick. I updated my answer with a link to some useful documentation. If this was helpful, you might kindly check the green arrow left of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your objects are members of the array.

```
my $o = $objects[0];
$o->method(@args);
```

or, shortly:

```
$objects[0]->method(@args);
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, keep in mind that Perl is not Java.

So, as appealing as it looks to you, do not use `new Class`. That is called *indirect object notation*. It looks cute and familiar, but it will bite you.

I am assuming `virtualCoffeeObject` is class which has accessors for the coffee type it represents. Did I mention, Perl is not Java?

Let's say you have the following barebones class:

```
package My::Coffee;

sub new {
   my $class = shift;
   bless { name => $_[0] } => $class;
}

sub name {
   my $self = shift;
   $self->{name};
}
```

And, given the names below:

```
# My array of coffeecup names
my @names = qw(Espresso Sumatran Java);
```

You want to create an array of `My::Coffee` objects with the corresponding names. In Perl, you would do:

```
 my @coffees = map My::Coffee->new($_), @names;
```

> *How do I get at the Espresso coffee cup object?*

There is no reason to presume there is only a single `My::Coffee` instance with name Espresso:

```
 my @espressos = grep $_->name eq 'Espresso', @coffees;
```

You can invoke methods on the elements of either array:

```
 say $_->name for @coffees;
```

or

```
 say $_->name for @espressos;
```

Did I mention Perl is not Java?

Answer (score 0):

first note that best practices are to call the "new" method (and all methods) with -> instead of like a subroutine, i.e., $object = Class->new();

```
for (@objects) {
   my $object = $_;

   #call methods on the object
   $object->method();

   #assign vars to method call result
   my $var = $object->method();

   #access the objects attributes directly (not advised)
   $var = $object->{attribute};
}
```

Comment: Using `'Class'->new` is still better, and `Class::->new` the best, but ugly.